# Angular custom input with ReactiveForm returns strings instead of numbers

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom Angular input component which has an `type` input property to set it on the input element, the type is a union type.

```
// The custom input component
export InputType = 'text' | 'password' | 'number'

export class InputComponent {
   @Input() type: InputType
}

<input [type]="type">

// How I use it
<custom-input type="number"></custom-input>
```

I have some issue to use this custom input in `ReactiveForms` with numbers. When I try to get the form values the numeric properties are strings. Instead when I hard-coded the type number in the HTML input when values are correctly in numbers

Comment: I guess it should be `<input type="type">`

Comment: should be `export type InputType = 'text' | 'password' | 'number'`. It's looks like work (See a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3erwai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)). Be sure pass to children the type property

Comment: @Eliseo I [forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxrcxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) your stackblitz and added the form control so it resemble more the real code and yes it works. I see that both inputs set the form control value as `number`. But in the real code I do practically the same thing (just some more components nesting) the number is saved as string. I found [#13243](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13243) still open and I am wondering if it has been fixed in Angular 14 (I am currently using 13).

Comment: I have a `PageComponent` > `MiddleComponent` > `InputComponent`. The first one contains the form group and some `MiddleComponent` with `InputType`. `InputComponent` binds the `InputType` to the HTML input and it receives from the parent.

Comment: Tried to update to Angular 14. Still doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**. Answers above are suitable for anything except the 'type' attribute. The only method to resolve this case I found is to use different *ngIf blocks with predefined (constant) input types:

```
<input *ngIf="inputType === 'number'" type="number" >
<input *ngIf="!inputType || inputType === 'text'">
... etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

First creat component by this command:

> ng g c custom-input

in ts component add below codes:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: `<input [type]="InputType"/>`,
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.scss']
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() InputType: string='';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Then use it in the child component as follows:

1. number input:

   <app-custom-input [InputType]="'number'">
2. text input:

   <app-custom-input [InputType]="'text'">
3. and etc...

Comment: I tried with a string `inputType` as you suggested but still the same result. When the input is used in a reactive form the value is a `string` instead of `number`.

Comment: try this: form = new FormGroup({
    FullName:  new FormControl(''),
    Age: new FormControl(Number),
  });